# Should I use a platform or a custom-build solution for my business?

Tags: social-networking, elgg, socialengine

I have an idea that involves social networking (note: it's not just a regular social networking site), and I'm wondering if I should use a social networking platform such as SocialEngine, Elgg, or some other, or get a developer and create a custom-build solution to meet my needs?

Answer (score 1):

Make a list of your requirements and if an existing platform meets your needs (even if it needs some tailoring) then go for it. It'll get you started quickly and allow you to focus on building the online community. You can always switch over to a custom solution if the site takes off as you'll then have the money to pay for its development. Good luck in any case!